# Where does the dependency property comes from when redefining control template?

Tags: wpf, templates, dependency-properties, textblock

Let say you have 2 WPF buttons. One uses TextBlock, not the other one.

```
<Button x:Name="Button1">
    <TextBlock>inside textblock</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

and

```
<Button x:Name="Button2">
   no textblock
</Button>
```

Both buttons use this template which sets the "Foreground" dependency property to white:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">            
   <Border Name="Border" TextElement.Foreground="White">
   <ContentPresenter/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The button with TextBlock has black text. The other one works fine. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of value inheritance as H.B. points out. Property value inheritance generally follows the logical tree.

In the first case:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1">
    <TextBlock>inside textblock</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

The TextBlock's logical parent is the Button, so it will inherit it's value from Button and so on up the logical tree. So in the following code, the TextBlock will be red:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" TextBlock.Foreground="Red">
    <TextBlock>inside textblock</TextBlock>
</Button>
```

In the second case:

```
<Button x:Name="Button2">
   no textblock
</Button>
```

A TextBlock is ultimately created by the ContentPresenter (see the ContentPresenter.ChooseTemplate method in ILSpy/Reflector). In this case, the TextBlock's logical parent is the ContentPresenter. So it will inherit it's value from ContentPresenter and so on up the logical tree, to the Border which has the White foreground defined.

This is documented briefly [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197.aspx#InheritanceContext).

Comment: Very nice, i always looked at the visual tree which was identical, it never occurred to me that the logical tree is responsible for the inheritance.

Comment: @H.B. - The [InheritanceBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.inheritancebehavior.aspx) property can make things worse, since it can short-circuit the value inheritance on an element-by-element basis.

Answer (score 1):

Cannot find a relevant reference for this, if you have a TextBlock that comes with its own styles and settings which may override the attached property you set outside.

Edit: Possibly an issue of [value inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753197%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in general.

Comment: Actually, the button with content directly set works fine. It's the one using TextBlock which has unexpected color.

Comment: Cannot find it, but the explicit creation of the TextBlock probably overrides the effects of the AttachedProperties, it is not quite clear how the TextBlock is created implicitly...

Answer (score 0):

If you have an implicit TextBlock style with colour in it then it won't pick the Foreground colour up, unless you explicitly do a template binding.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to get the value from the button. I want my ControlTemplate to set it hard-coded white. Explicitly template binding the foreground in the ContentPresenter sets the color to black.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're after and why are you trying to set the content colour on the Border. In any case, if you replace ContentPresenter with a ContentControl you can set Foreground on it, that might solve your problem.

Comment: You mean placing a border in the contentPresenter is maybe not a good practice? (Actually, I just want to understand better WPF behaviour so that I'm not surprised or confused to get black text where I expected it to be white.)

Comment: No, the Border is fine in your DataTemplate, just realised what got me confused is that you didn't paste the closing tag so it looked as if the ContentPresenter is outside the Border!